# how to save the image of facebook user form my facebook api to my database?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have registration page where i fetch user details suchas firstname and lastname and its image
my  question is how i can store the image of a user into my database?

Answer (score 1):

well I can give you example in which you don't store the image itself but the profile image's link to your database.

`$fb_access_token=$session['access_token'];
        $fbme = $facebook->api('/me');
        $photolink = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$fbme['id'].'/picture?type=square';

        $fbid = $fbme['id'];`

//connect to db
$query = "INSERT INTO users (fbid,photo_link) VALUES ('".$fbid."', '".$photolink."')";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

You can specify the picture size you want with the type argument, which should be one of square (50x50), small (50 pixels wide, variable height), normal (100 pixels wide, variable height), and large (about 200 pixels wide, variable height)

Comment: thanx but what will be the fields type in database for the image replyTomas Golnski

Comment: fbid int(30) or even up to 50 to be safe .. fb ids are veeery long

Comment: the photo_link put as text field

Comment: hEY  Thomas I already have userid (fetched as userid)so is it neceesary to add  $fbid = $fbme['id']; can u plz add  andshow in my query this my query mysql_query("INSERT INTO eventreport(userid,eid,fname,lname) VALUES ('$uid', '$eid','$fname','$lname') plz help

Comment: well if you are already fetching the user id before then there is no point to fetch it again ;) just use this query "INSERT INTO users (photo_link) VALUES ('".$photolink."')"

Comment: if this script is running not at the same stage as the script you are using to fetch the user_id (if the user_id is already in the database) then you will need to do something like that: "UPDATE users SET photo_link='".$photolink."' WHERE user_id=".$me['id']." LIMIT 1";